# RavenDB as MVC session storage

Tags: database, model-view-controller, ravendb

I have some questions:
Is it possible to use RavenDB as:
    1. Backend database as a persistent storage (instead of sql)
    2. As ASp.NET MVC Session storage (to store session data instead of HttpContext. This data will expire on user/tenant logout.
at the same time?

And if so, How

Thanks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, why not?
As for the session state storage - take a look at this: https://github.com/mjrichardson/RavenDbSessionStateStoreProvider